# Access decorators from multiple views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-decorators

As I am learning Django, I am running into this issue I have not found a solution for.

Imagine I have 5 apps in my project:

```
* project
* accounts
* profiles
* products
* services
```

In my accounts project, I have all of the logic for authentication and have created a `decorators.py` file under accounts that I would like to check from any of the apps.

Under accounts, in my `views.py`, I simply import the `decorators.py` as such:

```
from .decorators import *
```

At this point, however, I am not seeing how to import the same `decorators.py` from the `views.py` file in other apps.

Comment: `from accounts.decorators import ...`.

Comment: Please don't use a wildcard import, it is an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `PYTHON_PATH` is set at the project root, so you can import with:

```
from accounts.decorators import some_decorator
```

---

> **Note**: Please do [*not* use wildcard imports <sup>[quantifiedcode.com]</sup>](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/from_module_import_all_used.html).
> It makes the statement less predictable, it can easily result in failing code if you later decide to change what is exported in a certain module, and
> furthermore it can override variables.